# List open files without lsof/fuser at a particular path

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, proc, lsof

On a system that doesn't have `lsof` or `fuser`, is it possible to get a list of open files at a particular path?

E.g., I'm looking to dismount `/volume1` (a software RAID) to run `e2fsck` and can't, because it's busy. Is it possible using a minimal toolset to not only see open files, but also filter down to only those that are open at `/volume1` and below?

Comment: Check whether any of the symbolic links in `/proc/*/fd`, `/proc/*/cwd` and `/proc/*/exe` points to a file in `/volume1`.

Comment: ps ax | grep volume1

?

Comment: @berndbausch would you submit that as an answer, please?

Comment: @berndbausch see above.

Comment: Thanks that's fine. The answer is already there, no need for a twin answer. I am happy if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @berndbausch:

```
# find /proc/*/fd /proc/*/cwd /proc/*/exe -type l \
  -exec bash -c 'l=$1; p="$(readlink ${l})"; [[ -f "${p}" && "${p}" =~ \/var\/log ]] && echo "${p}"' {} {} \;
/var/log/audit/audit.log
/var/log/messages
/var/log/NetworkManager
/var/log/warn
/var/log/firewalld
/var/log/cups/error_log
/var/log/wpa_supplicant.log
/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```